# Access and process field in an Apache Camel exchange

Tags: java, apache-camel, ognl, mvel, enterprise-integration

In several of my camel routes, I need to access a field of an object, process it, and use it for something.

For example: Say I have an object of

```
class myClass {
  int fieldA;
  String fieldB;
}
```

which is used as an exchange header, say on `myOldHeader`. In my route definition, I want to access `fieldA` from this header, process it with, a function of some bean, say `String myIntTransform(int)`, and place the result into some other header. That is, I would like to have an element in my route definition similar to the following (pseudocode):

```
from(direct:input)
  .setHeader("myNewHeader").method("MyBean", "myIntTransform").on(header("myOldHeader").field("fieldA")
  .to(direct:output)
```

I know that Camel comes with a zoo of expression languages and DSLs for all sorts of tasks. But so far, I haven't found a convenient way to accomplish the above *without* having to put specific annotations (like `@Header`) on "myBean", which would create a tight coupling of beans I am trying to avoid.